# What are the cultural and military implications and applications of this magic system?

Tags: magic, culture

Ether-craft: ether is force that is both generated by living things and found almost everywhere in nature. Ether-crafters through birth or training can tap into this energy and use it for a variety of purposes.

Going with my sources the first ability developed is sensory, Crafters can feel the ether given off by all things. They have a general sense of a being's physical and emotional state.

Personal augmentations: Crafters can greatly augment their physical capabilities. the degree to which this can be done is determined by raw power,tolerance and skill. it's also possible to perform selective augmentation.

Psychically Aspected Ether waves: Crafters can broadcast ether waves that serve as medium for mental communication.

Physically Aspected Ether waves: Ether waves of this sort behave most like kinetic energy out of all the mundane energies. These vibratory-waves are conducted best by liquids, second by solids and third by vapor; only on certain high frequencies can vapors be used as an effective medium. Ether can be used to manipulate matter,as though one had an extra set of clumsy hands; practice results in finer control. Matter can be made to tense or relax, effecting it's strength and flexibility as long as ether is channelled through it. Force can be channels into matter to accelerate it, increase it's destructive potential; see Gambit from X-men for example, or to rip it a apart in a manner resembling the phenomenon of destructive-resonance.

Ether-Plasm: Ether can be used to manifest and control Plasm, the stuff that ghost are made of. A phenomenon somewhere between a force and a substance. Translucint and bluish silver color resembling vapour when at rest,but crackling like electriscity when agitated. Plasm can be used to blast targets, leaving damage that looks a mixture of impact and erosion. Plasma can also be be used to defend, field and envelopes protect from all manner of harm. It can also be modelled into simple shapes, it would take great knowledge and precision to create complex machines.

These abilities are the more esoteric.

Sublimation: the ability to partially or wholly shift matter into a "higher" and more malleable state/plane of existence. Intangiblility, Invisibility, Teleportation, Storage by "dematerialization" and the transfiguration of matter.
Eidolons/ apparitions: create subordinate psychic entities. The most basic of these are just bundles of programmed ether; such as scry-eyes that can be used to spy on distant locations. The more advanced and dangerous to produce are created by breaking off a piece of your own soul for use as the nucleus of a construct. These more advanced Eidolons can take physical form, a form which is influenced by the subconscious. Because they are extensions of their Crafter, the Crafter can be harmed through the Eidolon.

In developing this magic system I have created a versatile and dangerous tool. In order to get the most out of it in my WIP I need to know the related facts of what that tool can do and how it affects the people that use it and their culture.

Comment: I've edited a few spelling errors out. I'd suggest you include your overall question about your system at the end of this text to make it easier to figure out what you're asking

Comment: *All* the cultural and military implications? Do you want me to write a whole series of books or would one 500+ page novel be sufficient?

Comment: What aspect are you interested in culture? That is a very large topic. The question is literally, what impact does magic have on my world... Think about it.

Comment: @Philipp The gist of the ways in which you think this magic-system would effect a world would suffice.

Comment: @Vincent Mainly as it relates to personal combat,such as the the techniques that Battle-Mages might employ in battle. The major impact of this magic on warfare I've already figured out, massed armies would have never been used. Warfare would have all ways resembled modern combat. Small teams going after vital assets. The soldiers of this world in term of "class" would have been Ninja-Rangers. Small bands of versatile and mobile combatants.

Comment: This has the core of a good question but you need to be much more specific before it can be re-opened. You're asking for answers that cover a huge scope. Try adding the information from your comments into the question and at the same time limiting the scope as to what information you are looking for.

Comment: @Tim B I'm not sure how I could distil this in to something more wieldly;i'd be open to suggestions I've created a tool and want it it's performance tested;perhaps this was no the place for that. My core interest is in seeing what kind of fighting-techniques would come out of the system.

Comment: @Trismegistus Then narrow it down to that to start with. You can always add more follow on questions later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Your Magic Affects Everything In Wild Ways

I suggest thinking about what professions would benefit from any of those abilities. A dock worker has increased strength and stamina. Why wouldn't I hire him? A spy who can mentally talk to other members of his team, all the while maintaining his cover. Why would I employ any other type of spy? A nurse or doctor who can make mental contact with their patients, and know what they're feeling / thinking without even asking. There goes the controversy around comas!

Would a person without these abilities ever stand a chance *in any occupation* competing against those with them? The closest I can come to is writing, but the poor non-magic user can't write about how that tree is feeling, or the waves of emotion that a pop-concert/riot/athletic event/monastery could produce. In short, these magic users would be superior to non-magic users. Everyone, who is unhindered to do so, would aspire to learn how to use magic.

What about human rights? Those with magic are obviously superior to those without it. Can you imagine a [eugenics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugenics) movement with this kind of world? Even if everyone *can* learn to do it, what about those that think it is a taboo?

These abilities in war? You could cause fuel tanks to explode. Rip bodies up from the inside, as their blood is a liquid. I'm sure you could come up with other uses that are too terrible to mention.

Also, if this magic was accessible from the start of human history, it would alter the course of it so drastically that it would be entirely unrecognizable from our own, actual history. Slavery, which has been particularly widely practiced by many humans in many ages, may have developed differently. It may have been side-stepped entirely, resulting in a cultures which are more egalitarian than many of our earthly ones.

## Suggestions For Development of Your Magic

- "Sublimation" already refers to a physical process, where a solid
  piece of matter turns directly into a gas, "skipping" the liquid
  phase. While it sounds neat, it may rub scientists and individuals of
  a certain mindset wrong. I would suggest another name.
- Determine how usable this magic actually is. What is the cost of
  using this? Does it take a physical toll on the body or mind? If
  there is no risk involved, what prevents everyone from using it? If
  everyone can and does use it, how does it affect their day-to-day
  lives? This will go a long way into figuring out how it affects that world.

Comment: Well the limits are pretty much the standards for a Force based magic system push to far and you die. specifically you begin to disintegrate like your being consumed from within by an invisible and smokeless flame. While the soul has vast power the body and minds are imperfect conduits, and can quickly be destroyed by the very power that sustains them. In fact it's a major plot point that the Peoples or Tribes are not that good at using ether...when compared to their enemies.

Comment: Sublimation was the best term that I could come up with,it was to the point and relates to the word Sublime. Taking things to a higher, a more sublime state is part of was supposed to do;Flux is an alternative term that I'd been considering.